# how to change the height of safari extension at runtime?

Tags: javascript, html, css, safari, safari-extension

I have developed a safari extension and it is working well when it comes to the logic. But my problem is that i am not able to change the width and height of the popover at runtime. So can someone suggest me how to dynamically change the height and width of the popover according to the content?

Answer (score 1):

From a script in the popover page, use `safari.self.height`. Set it to the number of pixels you want the height to be. For example:

```
safari.self.height = document.body.scrollHeight;
```